# Using field obtained in awk command to grep

Tags: linux, awk

I want to pass the field next to the `u_test` string with FS as `,` and also line not beginning with `#` to a system command, which is grep in my case, to find the line containing that string in the `top.v` file.

```
BEGIN{FS=","}

{
    if($0 !~ /^#/){
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
            if($i ~ /u_test/){
                a=$(i+1);
                cmd = "grep '\$(i+1)' top.v";
                printf("%s\n",a);
                system(cmd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't seem to work.

Comment: could you give an example input as well as a description of what you try to achieve (i.e. example output) ?

Comment: Suppose input to this script contains record as u_test,abcd,pqrs,wyxc ...I want to extract 'abcd' which is next to u_test field and grep this string in another file top.v

Comment: You need to show us the *exact* input and the *exact* expected output.  Please [edit] your question to update it with these details.

Comment: It is **EXTREMELY** unlikely that calling grep from a loop inside awk is the right solution to this or any other problem. Edit your question to include sample input and expected output so we can start to help you figure out the right approach and eventual implementation. Also, see http://xyproblem.info/.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the way you construct your `cmd` string. Indeed:

```
cmd = "grep '\$(i+1)' top.v";
print cmd;
```

gives you `grep '$(i+1)' top.v`, hence `\$` is treated as a plain `$` and is not replaced by the awk variable.

So, instead, use:

```
 cmd = "grep '"$(i+1)"' top.v";
```

or simply:

```
cmd = "grep '"a"' top.v";
```

Also, I suggest you use an real awk condition instead of the `if`:

```
$0 !~ /^\#/ { # replaces the if
    # your code with the for loop
}
```

---

For the fun of it, here is a one-liner using `sed` and `xargs` doing the same:

```
cat ex.txt | sed 's/^#.*//' | sed -n 's/.*u_test,\([^,]*\).*$/\1/p' | xargs -I{} grep {} top.v
```